# Why do I have to type the full name of my model in store configuration

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This might be a silly question but why do I have to type the full name of my model when configuring my store?

I already declare the models I'm gonna be using in 'app.js' in the model array

```
model: [
    'Estatus',
    'EstatusSegurosMensualModel'
],

Ext.define('Monitor.store.EstatusSegurosMensualStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'EstatusSegurosMensualModel', // I would like to do this
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        .
        .
        .

Ext.define('Monitor.store.EstatusSegurosMensualStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Monitor.model.EstatusSegurosMensualModel', // not cool
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        .
        .
        .
```

Is it only so I can have different 'Employees' models in different packages?

Comment: Please  bother to explain why the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `model` string is used as an argument for [`Ext.ModelManager.getModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/ModelManager.html#Ext-ModelManager-method-getModel) and `getModel` expects the id of the model or the model instance:

```
 getModel: function(id) {
        var model = id;
        if (typeof model == 'string') {
            model = this.types[model];
        }
        return model;
    }
```